# How to map data on button click event in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react js and springboot to develop a module and mongoDb is
used as the database. I'm using a button to display shipping details. when users click on create delivery button, data must be
updated and it's working well.

The issue I have is, on the next button
"view shipping details". I want to map data to a different table on
button click even. I'm getting data to shipping array. I also mapped
it. but it doesn't display when I click on the button.

this is the button

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style={{marginLeft:"0px"}} 
         onClick={async(e)=>{
            try{
             var url=`/getList/${detail.orderId}`
            //  var result=  await axiosInstance.get(url);
            console.log(detail.orderId)
            await  axiosInstance.get("/getList/"+detail.orderId)
            .then(res => {
            
              console.log(res.data);
              setShipping(res.data);
          })
            //  console.log(result);
            }catch(e){
              console.log(e);
            }
          }}>View shipping details</button></td>
```

this is where I map it

```
<div id="shipping">
<table className="table table-striped">
  <thead class="table-light">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>Full Name</th>
                                            <th>Address</th>
                                            <th>City</th>
                                            <th>Province</th>
                                            <th>Zip Code</th>
                                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                                            
                                        </tr>

        
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
                shipping.map
                    (ship=>(
                  <tr key={ship.orderId}>
                  <td>{ship.orderId}</td>
                   <td>{ship.fullname}</td>
                   <td>{ship.address}</td>
                   <td>{ship.city}</td>
                   <td>{ship.province}</td>
                   <td>{ship.zipcode}</td>
                   <td>{ship.phonenumber}</td>
                  
                </tr>))}
              </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your shipping state is undefined at first render?
Try add to check if shipping exist like this:

```
  { shipping && shipping.map
                    (ship=>(
                  <tr key={ship.orderId}>
                  <td>{ship.orderId}</td>
                   <td>{ship.fullname}</td>
                   <td>{ship.address}</td>
                   <td>{ship.city}</td>
                   <td>{ship.province}</td>
                   <td>{ship.zipcode}</td>
                   <td>{ship.phonenumber}</td>
                </tr>))}
```

Comment: at first render it's undefined as I have to get order Id from the displayed data

Comment: I'm successfully logging data to the console but I'm calling this this mapped data in another table. so when I click on the button, it goes blank but I can see the response in console. That mean button click function works fine, but mapping it in another table in the same page doesn't work